# Why did I die as Tryndamere in the fountain?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday I was playing Tryndamere top. We had a large advantage and managed to destroy everything up to the nexus tower. During the final minutes of the game I decided to fountain dive the enemy Lux that just respawned but despite activating my ultimate, I died really quickly.

Isn't Tryndamere's ultimate called ***Undying Rage***?

In the wiki it says: ***Tryndamere becomes completely immune to death for 5 seconds, refusing to be reduced below 30/50/70 Health and instantly gaining 50/75/100 Fury.***

So why did I die in the fountain? Shouldn't I be unkillable for 5 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fountain will attack using a beam that deals 1000 true damage every 0.5 seconds. This beam will **ignore most immunity effects** including Tryndamere's ultimate. Note that the damaging beam will also ignore shields and revival effects.

The only effects not ignored are the following:

- Untargetability (Fizz E, Vladimir Pool)
- Stasis (Zhonya's, Bard R)

And aggro can be traded like usual, meaning champions that go untargetable are dropped from the turret aggro table as usual.

[Source](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Nexus_Obelisk)

Comment: Note, that this effect was only added to the laser after the game was released for quite a while. In an earlier state of the game, Tryndamere could easily tower-dive with hiw ultimate. [Not Tryndamere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gI1aeS5H1Vs), but basically what I was refering to

Comment: [And a Tryndamere one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=se1_pxNCUdw)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yeah I remember that^^ Although that got removed around the start of season two. (Also the game was still pretty broken back then).

Comment: Damn... Season 1 way more brutal...